# How to handle onclick functions with parameters in vue js components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have following template with **data** as a global variable that contains all the data:

```
<template id="animal-list">
        <div class="animalImage">
            <img :src="data.imageSource" />
        </div>
        <h3>{{data.name}}</h3>
        <p>{{data.teaser}}<span @click="showArticle(data.id)">open details</span>
        </p>
        <p>{{data.description}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Now my question is, how can I declare my id from data in the click function in the span as a parameter ? Is that possible somehow?

Unfortunately my test says, that the id is undefined.

Comment: What you have should work: if `data` has an `id`, your `showArticle` method should receive it as param. Please create a [mcve] reproducing the bug you're experiencing. You haven't posted the cause of the described bug yet. The most probable cause for your bug (from what you're showing) is that your `data` doesn't have an `id`. My wild guess is that you're expecting the `data` function of a Vue instance to produce `data.id`. **It does not!**. It produces properties directly on the instance: `id` (no `data.` prefix).

Answer (score 0):

Your property `id` in the data does not exist.

You can pass to function as argument all data like `showArticle(data)`, and check all properties in function; for example:

```js
function showArticle(data) { console.log(data) }
```

Comment: in data there is an id, definitely. when i do that what you suggested, everything is 0.

Comment: if everything is 0 means you really have 0. You need to create online example to reproduce the error after that we could simply correct the code to get what you need, it's a basic JavaScript and Vue